# Melhor prática para próxima numeração PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma aplicação PHP + MySQL, e preciso que seja criada uma próxima numeração de um registro de acordo com uma outra coluna. Por isso, o AUTO_INCREMENT não resolve, pelo fato de sempre somar mais um, indiferente da PRIMARY KEY. E minhas tabelas são InnoDB. Qual seria a melhor prática? 
Pois se eu realizar um SELECT MAX() para pegar a próxima numeração, corre o risco de uma outra sessão realizar no mesmo instante e duplicar ou gerar erro.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você pode explicar melhor essa parte: "e preciso que seja criada uma próxima numeração de um registro de acordo com uma outra coluna", mais detalhes?

Comment: Eu já tive problemas com duplicação de registros também, e não queria usar o auto_increment pois dava alguns saltos no intervalo de números. O que eu fiz foi uma função de SELECT MAX() mesmo e o incrementava, mas eu fazia isso tudo no momento de inserir o registro, e em nenhum momento antes. Isso já resolveu me problema.